# How to fix spaces from top of page and header?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I can't delete spaces between top of page and header (testing sites). 
Here's the site on WordPress: http://telcforkids.hostenko.com/

How can I fix this problem?

I can't change all code of my page, because I'm using wordPress, I also looked in Google inspector, but I can't see what I need to change. Now code from body to first word look this:

```
<body class="">
   <section>
     <div id="page-zones__template-widgets__feature-featurehome" class="widget feature " data-widget-type="feature" data-uniqueid="page-zones__template-widgets__feature-featurehome">
     <div class="feature-bgimg"  style="background-image: url('//d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/bkpam2147067_bkpam2147067_img_6848_resize_1.jpg'); background-position: center 42%" >
     <div class="content">
     <div class="spare wrapper"><h2><span>Here you can find courses for children</span></h2>
```

Comment: Please show a minimal re-create *in the question*. Don't expect people to go to some random website.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have lot of paddings :

Example 1

```
.section-container, 
.gdlr-item-start-content, 
.gdlr-parallax-wrapper, 
.gdlr-color-wrapper {
        /* padding-top: 70px; */
    }
```

Example 2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can u look again on questing i edit question (add new information)?

Answer (score 0):

```
.section-container, .gdlr-item-start-content, .gdlr-parallax-wrapper, .gdlr-color-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

You also have a load of head code and paragraphs in the middle of your page

```
<p>
<p>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.londonsmp.co.uk">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//d282ykz6vx01th.cloudfront.net/bkpam2147067_site_70.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//d1se4t4tzjp7kt.cloudfront.net/32ee23f/compiled/photo-swipe.css">
<p>
<style class="js-webfont" data-woff-cache="//d1se4t4tzjp7kt.cloudfront.net/32ee23f/seven/fonts/lato.woff.json" data-ttf-cache="//d1se4t4tzjp7kt.cloudfront.net/32ee23f/seven/fonts/lato.ttf.json" data-fallback-stylesheet="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin" data-name="lato">
```

I think you could hide this with

```
.main-content-container > .gdlr-main-content > p {display: none;}
```

You may have to experiment a little.

Comment: Thank you, but can u look again on questing i edit question (add new information)?